# Can't access checked property of input

Tags: javascript

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="price_change('<?=$service_new_price;?>',this.id)" <?php echo $checked ?> value="<?php echo $entityId; ?>" id="service-option-<?php echo $entityId; ?>" class="service-option" name="service-option[]">
```

its showing else all the time when i click on checkbox i will be thankful if someone help me

```js
function price_change(value, id) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML;
  var n_price = x.replace(/[^\w\s.]/gi, '')

  if (id.checked) {
    var new_price = +n_price + +value;
    console.log('checked');
  } else {
    var new_price = +n_price - +value;
    console.log(id, 'uncheck');
  }
  //document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML = new_price;
  //document.getElementsByClassName('price')[1].innerHTML = new_price;
}
```

Comment: What does console says?

Comment: When you debug this, what's the value of `id.checked`?  What is `id` that's being passed to this function?

Comment: doesn't look like you are evaluating for anything with (id.checked).

Comment: How is the function being called? Show your markup as well.

Comment: What happens when you step through it in a debugger? [Don't know how to use the debugger? Here's a tutorial.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Comment: We need to see the code that is calling this function.

Comment: this is checkbox id which showing in console but not working in if condition

Comment: @amphetamachine: That tutorial covers debugging Chrome **extensions**, which is a bit of a hurtle. Perhaps [this one instead](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/).

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(id)`?

Comment: if id is checkbox id, you can not write id.checked. first you have to find checkbox using that id, then you can find checked state of that checkbox

Comment: i added my html and php code @binriedMe

Comment: i get checkbox id my if condition is not working @Tyler

Comment: Please choose a more explicit title for your next posts. The title must be explicit and sum up your problem.

Comment: Your HTML seems to have been infected with a virus known as PHP. Since we can't parse your PHP (e.g, we have no idea what the value of `service_new_price` is). Please show the rendered HTML, which you can see using the View Source functionality of your browser.

Comment: Also, while you're editing your question with a [mcve], please change the title to describe your question, not the fact that you need help with JavaScript. See [ask] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your input's `id` as a string into your function, but you are treating it like the input object. Instead of passing the `id`, pass the object itself:

```
onclick="price_change('<?=$service_new_price;?>',this)"
```

Then you can dot into the object properties:

```
function price_change(value, obj) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML;
  var n_price = x.replace(/[^\w\s.]/gi, '')

  if (obj.checked) {
    var new_price = +n_price + +value;
    console.log('checked');
  } else {
    var new_price = +n_price - +value;
    console.log(id, 'uncheck');
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
*To address your comment regarding being able to see the value of `id` in the console:*

You're able to see the value of id in the console because it exists - as a string. You can't say `<string>.checked` because string doesn't have a property called checked - only your input object does.

Simply put, pass the object, or retrieve the object based on the id that you pass in (I prefer the former).

Comment: but i am getting id in console but just if conditions is not working i am getting id when i click

Comment: You're getting the `id` in the console because it exists - **as a string**. You can't say `<string>.checked` because string doesn't have a property called checked.

Comment: can i ask on thing more

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```js
const priceChange = (value, id) => {
 // You need to get the element, not just use its ID
  const checkbox = document.querySelector('#'+id);
  if(checkbox.checked){
   // Change price
    console.log(checkbox.checked);
  }
  else{
   // do something else
    console.log(checkbox.checked);
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type='checkbox' id='myCheckbox' onclick='priceChange(10, this.id)' /> Checkbox</label>
```

Comment: why the downvote? Does it not help solve the problem?